# How to search for a string in sql that starts in a specific letter and then has a number?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I need to pick out a sum of all the postcodes that start with W then all that start with WC then all that start with N

Example postcodes are WC1 1AA, W1 1AA, N20 2BZ, W4 5BR

For the WC I'm struggling to make it happen, my query is looking like this

```
select sum(balls) from table where postcodes like 'WC%' and postcodes like '__[0-9]'
```

2 underscores there, doesn't really work

Outcome is something like

```
area | sum
  WC | 20
  W  | 14
  N  | 23
...
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to have a look at this document. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your question says nothing about numbers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've provided a sample postcode but okay, not sure how it would change anything

Comment: Perhaps you need `... LIKE 'WC[0-9]%'`

Comment: @BJones if I do a like 'WC%' it returns me 433 rows while with your query I get an incorrect 0

Comment: So you're saying it doesn't return `WC1 1AA` like the example you provided?.. Try adding another wildcard - `... LIKE 'WC%[0-9]%'`

Comment: @BJones nope, and with select * fromtable where postcodes like 'WC%[0-9]%' then it still returns 0 rows

Comment: @BJones: LIKE does not support ranges like that or regular expressions

Comment: @Luffydude, how about instead of like use `...similar to 'WC[0-9]%';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator does [not support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) patterns like that, you are looking for [regular expression pattern](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

```
select sum(balls) 
from table 
where postcodes ~ 'WC[0-9]+';
```

Comment: Oh! it's still returning me some wrong results. doing select *
from table where postcodes ~ 'N[0-9]+'; it is returning me a bunch of results like "EN2 0EG"

Comment: Solved the problem by doing select * from table where postcodes ~ 'N[0-9]+' AND postcodes like 'N%'